# deploying to Windows Mobile 6 Professional Emulator - SLOW !

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there a way to speed up deployment to emulator.
Whenever i hit debug it takes almost a minute for the deploy to complete.

thanx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you closing the emulator between debugging sessions? The delay you report sounds like you are. Leave the emulator window open and you won't need to wait for windows mobile to boot each time you deploy your app.

Comment: actualy i leave it opened. I just cancel debug and then do debug again. If i monitor whats happening i see this: buid completes fast, deploy also ... then on the device the spinning logo keeps spinning for like 30 seconds before the app opens....